# IpcChannel MSDN Example : Cannot load type {0} Exception

Tags: c#, ipc

I followed the MSDN example for the IpcChannel class :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel.aspx

I made two Console Application Projects :

The client :

```
namespace IPC_Client_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand)]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the channel.
            IpcChannel channel = new IpcChannel();
            // Client code
```

And the server :

```
namespace IPC_Server_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand)]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the server channel.
            IpcChannel serverChannel =new IpcChannel("localhost:9090");
            // Server Code
```

I run the Server then launch the Client and I get an exeption at this line :

```
Console.WriteLine("The remote object has been called {0} times.", service.GetCount());
```

Cannot load type 'IPC_Client_Test.RemoteObject, IPC Client Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I started using IPC, I've search over the web and found some examples by Zach Smith, from TechRepublic.  I think you could start by this.  It helped me to make a basic IPC.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-ipc-channels-and-net-framework-20-to-communicate-between-processes/6143016

Comment: Thanks that sample was better explained, now I can see my mistake. The shared object should be in a separate project/solution.